# Pre_get_posts Gives 404 on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to filter the query on a sub page called "Ask Question" to list all of the recent questions submitted by users, but I get a 404 when going to the page. Flushing the permalink structure did not fix the issue. It is currently set to Month and Name.

Creating a new question works properly and I'm able to access the new posts. The custom taxonomies work correctly as well, however the archive pages do not.

This is the code that I'm using.

**Post type**

```
function question_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Questions', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Question', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Questions', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Question:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Questions', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Question', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Question', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New Question', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Question', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Question', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search questions', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No questions found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No questions found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => '/ask/question',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'question', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Question', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 20,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'question', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'question_post_type', 0 );
```

**Taxonomy**

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_question_taxonomy') ) {

    // Register Custom Taxonomy
    function custom_question_taxonomy()  {
        $labels = array(
            'name'       

            => _x( 'Question Types', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Question Type', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Question Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Question Type:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Question Types with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Question Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Question Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Question Types', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'question-type',
        'with_front'                 => false,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'question-type', 'question', $args );
}


    add_action( 'init', 'custom_question_taxonomy', 0 );

}
```

**Query**

```
function question_posts_query( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'question' ) || $query->is_page(3001) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'question' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'question_posts_query' );
```

**My page loop**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="post-content">

          <?php the_content(__('Read More &raquo;', 'gp_lang')); ?>

          <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'question-type', '<div class="category"><span>Category: </span>', '', '</div>' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do the pages resolve without the filter being applied? Do you get a 404 on both the custom post type's archive index page *and* static page ID 3001? (Note: watch your Boolean conditions. You've got an `AND` in series with an `OR`. I would suggesting putting the `OR` conditionals in parentheses.

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes, the page resolves without the filter. I do get a 404 on the post type archive page.

Answer (score 2):

Changing a query for the `page` post type via `pre_get_posts` is a bit tricky, and maybe not worth the potential issues involved. If you inspect the generated SQL, it's looking for your requested pagename in the `question` post type, which is why you get the 404.

The solution is to delete the page, so WordPress will load a post type archive by default, or keep the page and use `WP_Query` within the template to load the custom posts.

Comment: Using wp_query on the page does work, though its not the best solution in the long run for dynamically displaying content with flexibility. The archive not working is still a problem.

Comment: why do you have a page where you want a post type archive? maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to do, the path of your page and how it relates to your post type archive isn't clear to me.

Comment: The Ask page displays a list of questions submitted by the user along with a submission form. Its designed as a Q/A. I want to use the default archive for the question post type to give users access to the older questions (answered or not) listed by the month and year.

Comment: for the default post type archive, change your slug to `'ask/question'` without the leading slash. as I mention in my answer, the `pre_get_posts` filter to load posts on the `page` post type will never work quite right, though I don't understand why `WP_Query` wouldn't work for you in this case, perhaps you could elaborate on that.

Comment: How would you remove the current page ID from this main query? That's why I get 404 ... this part in SQL query: AND (wp_posts.ID = '2') which is current page ID ...